# Including D3 in my Angular App using Bower Install D3, with typescript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, angularjs-directive

I have bower installed D3 (bower install D3). I am working to incorporate D3 into my Angular application but when I try to inject D3 as an dependency in the core app I get a "**D3 module is not found you either have forgot to load it or misspelled it**". So I solve it by creating a small D3 module based on the Stack Overflow Question here: [Why copy D3 source into an Angular Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434742/why-copy-d3-source-into-an-angular-service)

```
angular.module("d3").factory("d3Service, function (){
      var d3;
      d3 = window.d3;
      return d3;
}
```

Then I inject that into my Angular application as follows:

```
anuglar.module("main", ["d3"]).directive("test", function (d3Service){
    return {
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                d3Service.d3().then(function(d3){
                // d3 Code here
                }
             }
        }
```

When I do this I get an error saying the d3 factory must return something from $GET method...which is occurring because the d3 variable in my factory is undefined.

Why is that d3 variable undefined in my "d3Service? And I'm really wondering why do I even have to create this d3 module if I'm using bower install D3. Shouldn't D3 be available globally and the once its injected be usable? I have typescript "reference" paths pulling in the typescript definition for D3.

I'm working in the constraints of typescript so that is making it harder. It would be much easier to just be able to require the d3 and set it equal to a d3 variable. The reference path in typescript only allows you to get .ts files so I can't get the d3.js in the gulp build file. I can't copy and paste the source code into that d3 module because the source code is Javascript and would error in a .ts file, and would be hell to go through all of that and convert to typescript.

I shouldn't have to create that "d3" module should I if I'm using bower install? Why am I getting module not found error when I try to inject d3 into the angular app without creating that "d3" module myself.

Help is very much appreciated. Been working on this one a while.

Comment: The `d3Service` itself is the `d3` object that is being returned. Writing `d3Service.d3` is same as `d3.d3`, which wouldn't work!

Comment: Alright but regardless the d3 module is returning undefined..so that must not be the right sytnax to get the d3 object from the bower install..is there a better way? Also, if I don't want to do d3Service.d3() then would it just be d3Service.then()....?

Comment: Why would you do a `.then()` on the `d3` object? It is not a promise object that is being returned. You can just work on it like this: `d3Service.select('body')`