# How to Use D3 to Angular Project from Bower Install D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, bower

I am trying to include D3 into my Angular Application but can't seem to load the D3 from the Bower Install because Angular says it can't find it or it was mis-spelled. The application is set up to use gulp to get the bower_components and build from there. Is there something different with d3 that keeps it from being included the gulp build process?

Here is my component, I'm not able to get access to the D3 source code. Shouldn't I be able to access that from the bower install? I've seen some stack overflow questions where they say to create a simple "d3" module and return a d3 variable from it in the factory, but I get undefined from window.d3...?

```
   angular.module("diagram", ["d3"]).directive("ersDiagram", ["$compile", "$document", function($compile:ng.ICompileProvider, $document:ng.IDocumentService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "diagram/template/diagram.html",
        scope: {
            nodes: "=",
            edges: "=",
            autoResizeGraph: "@?",
            enableMouseWheelZoom: "@?",
            selectedNode: "=?",
            selectedEdge: "=?",
            height: "@?",
            onSelected: "&?",
            onEdgeSelected: "&?",
            direction: "@?",
            enableZoomButtons: "@?"
        },
        controller: DiagramComponent,
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        link: function (scope:ng.IScope, elem:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs:ng.IAttributes, ctrl:any) {
                //d3 code here
                //get undefined for all d3 code
          }
```

I don't understand why I can't just access D3 by injecting it into the application? Could it have something to do with gulp not including it in the build? And does anybody know, if a common case, how to get D3 to be included in the build?

Been stuck for a while, help is very much appreciated!

If you need to see any more specific code just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are not making the d3 module,so how can you write something like this `angular.module("diagram", ["d3"])`..

The correct way to do it is first make a module called d3.
In this we load the script via ajax and return its promise.

```
angular.module('d3', [])
  .factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope',
    function($document, $q, $rootScope) {
      var d = $q.defer();

      function onScriptLoad() {
        // Load client in the browser
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          d.resolve(window.d3);
        });
      }
      // Create a script tag with d3 as the source
      // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
      // has been loaded
      var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
      scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
      scriptTag.async = true;
      scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
      scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
      }
      scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

      var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      s.appendChild(scriptTag);

      return {
        d3: function() {
          return d.promise;
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Inside your html do.

```
   <div my-directive></div>
```

Make a directive to lookup for attribute `my-directive`.

The directive's link function will make use of the d3service injected in directive like this.

```
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
      //make your svg
      var svg = d3.select(element[0])
        .append('svg')
        .style('width', '400')
        .style('height', '500')
      svg.append("circle").attr("r", 10).attr("cx", 100).attr("cy", 100).style("fill", "red");
    });
  };
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nV0hSVBoPLQGeQavvhIj?p=preview)

Inspired by the blog [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html)

Comment: Thanks Cyril..I'm using bower install D3 so I'm trying to avoid using script tags, or do I still need the script tag with bower? Why do I have to create a D3 module if I am using bower install - isn't that essentially a module itself? I have tried creating a d3 module as well, I saw something in another post in the first answer but I get undefined in the d3 variable I am returning from the factory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434742/why-copy-d3-source-into-an-angular-service

Comment: In my answer the d3 module is the angular module. Its the way to make modules in angular1. Bower will never make it for you. If bower has already pulled in all your dependency in your html then simply drop the line...`[d3]` in here`angular.module("diagram", ["d3"])` and use d3 directly in the link function.

Comment: Ok yeah I have gulp building the files from all of my bower_components but when I try to inject d3 and use it directly I get "d3 is not defined".I see d3 in my bower_components but for some reason I can access everything else but d3